# how to login and sign up in android using web service in android

Tags: android, web-services, web, android-studio

How to login and sign up in android using web service . 
see below:
First name
Second Name 
Address
Email

Sign up (Button)

need code of sign up using api in android

Comment: So, you need the code. I need a new Porsche Carrera.

Comment: Always try and then ask this is not a correct manner to ask your que.....if u have tried any thing then it is good for u and for us to explain as well....

Comment: I think I love you @FrankN.Stein

Comment: I m Newbie thats y i m asking the code or any example , if u will provide then it will be helpful for me

Comment: But this is not the scope of this site. You must show what you tried and it is not working. Then we can help you fixing that or propose some alternatives. But you can't explicitly ask for code.

Comment: see the code below . i try this but not getting any response

Answer (score 0):

You can try the JSoup library. This is a java library which support web services. See: http://jsoup.org